# How can I change a cell of a TiledMapLayer?

Tags: java, libgdx

For some reason the following code doesn't change the graphic of the tile,
it sets it to `null`.

Any idea why that is?

```
public class Coin extends InteractiveTileObject {
    private final int COPPER_COIN = 4; 

    private static TiledMapTileSet tileSet;

    public Coin(World world, TiledMap map, Rectangle bounds) {
        super(world, map, bounds);
        tileSet = map.getTileSets().getTileSet("items");
        fixture.setUserData(this);
        setCategoryFilter(Constants.COIN_BIT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHeadHit() {
        getCell().setTile(tileSet.getTile(4));
    }
}
```

Here is my `getCell()` method:

```
public TiledMapTileLayer.Cell getCell(){
    TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get(1);
    return layer.getCell((int)(body.getPosition().x * Constants.PPM / 128),
        (int)(body.getPosition().y * Constants.PPM / 128));
}
```

Comment: What is returned by `tileSet.getTile(4))`?  Have you verified that it is returning the `TiledMapTile` you expect?  The [documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/TiledMapTileSet.html#getTile-int-) suggests that the `getTile(int)` method may return `null` if the specified tile doesn't exist.

Comment: 4 could also be (or is COPPER_COIN) the 1 is the second Layer, in my case Graphics Layer. Instead of 1 could also set it to .get("Graphics Layer"). Doesnt work either..

Comment: That doesn't answer my question; step through your code with a debugger and determine what the return value of `tileSet.getTile(4)` is; you can also print it to the console using: `System.out.println(tileSet.getTile(4))`.  I have a hunch that this value will be `null` based on the code you've provided and the problem you're describing, but I can't know for sure without knowing what the contents of the `tileSet` object are.

Comment: Is your "items" tileset the first tileset in tiled?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the tileset "items" is the first tileset defined in Tiled you won't get the tile you expect when you do

```
tileSet.getTile(4)
```

The index of tiles in other tilesets continues after the index in the previus tileset. So if you have 90 tiles in you first tileset, lets call that "tiles" then your first tile in tileset "items" will be 91.

This means you would have to do:

```
getCell().setTile(tileSet.getTile(94));
```

If you look at the tiles in Tiled you will still be told that the tiles IDs starts with 0. But this is not the ID you need when you call it with .getTile()